# Specific height width for background video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I'm using videobackground.js for setting background video, I want to specify the height width for the video,

My code is:

```
$('.vid').prepend('<div class="video-background"></div>');
$('.video-background').videobackground({
videoSource: [['video/2.webm', 'video/webm']],
loop : true
});
```

Html code is:

```
<div class="vid">

</div>
```

How to specify the height width for the video, if I specify height width full video not showing

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the following plugin: http://georgepaterson.github.io/jquery-videobackground/

`.video-background` appears to be the container for the full screen video, so if you state the height and width of `.video-background` in your CSS, this should work. I've tried this successfully in developer tools on Chrome.

Comment: already tried , but no use , if i specify height and width to .video-background the some parts of the video is not displaying

Comment: Hi Steve, it looks like the `video` element has the following CSS applied: `min-width:100%; min-height:100%;`. If you override this by setting `min-width:inherit; min-height:inherit;` on `.video-background video` this should resize the video itself. You can then set a particular height and width on the video element too.